# How can i create paypal subscribe button with only one billing cycle after trial period?

Tags: paypal, wordpress, paypal-subscriptions

I am new to creating Paypal payment buttons in which i want to use subscribe button with my plan. In this i want to limit my subscription cycle to only 1 billing cycle but Paypal has minimum 2 cycles in drop down when i am using payment standard.

I have program to sell for 497$ and i want to offer $1 trial period and after 1 week trial i want to charge another 496$. I want to then take customers to my registration page where i have set up membership website in WordPress using Wishlist Member. So i can use only subscribe button if i want to use wishlist as it is not compatible with installment button and also in my country (India) Paypal is not offering such advanced buttons.

Any subsequent help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack as the PayPal Subscription buttons do not support 'delayed payments' but it would be like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@yourdomain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test subscription">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="SgtPooki">
<input type="hidden" name="a2" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t2" value="W">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="496.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

**The text that appears on the checkout page at PayPal, which you cannot change, will say:**

> Then $1.00 USD for the next week
>
> $496.00 USD for each month, for 1 installments